# Where is the Smalltalk Archive gone?

Tags: smalltalk

I'm an old Smalltalk programmer (back in the early 90ties of the last century), and in that days, all Smalltalk "open source" (the term was not coined yet), all was available at the Manchester Smalltalk archive. This was moved later then to the [UIUC Smalltalk Archive](http://st-www.cs.illinois.edu/archive.html). I tried today to find my old entries there, but the archive is not available any more. Does anyone know how to retrieve the old content? Is there any place where the Smalltalk archive is archived?

Comment: I've no idea about that, but I'm in a few Smalltalk lists, and there are a lot of "historic" ppl there who might know... You should probably get on the most popoular smalltak lists and try your luck there... Try the lists for Pharo, Squeak, VisualWorks, GemStone, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/languages/smalltalk/st.cs.uiuc.edu/Smalltalk/ contains a lot of mirrored code from the archive.

Comment: Thank's a lot, I have found there some of the content I missed, but not all. But is definitivly a good starting point.

Comment: After sending some emails to old accounts, which most bounced, I give up now and accept this as the best answer now. If anyone finds more, I would be interested in the future ...

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.world.st/

http://forum.world.st/Smalltalk-f1294792.topics.html

are good links for your posts and research. I have heard of your archives, but don't know what happened to them either.

Comment: Thank's a lot fro the pointer, I looked up some of the lists and cites, but did not find any information there. I try now to reach Ralph Johnson from the University of Illinois, hope he can give some information.